# xpath how to extract the element itself and one of its child?

Tags: xpath

I'm fetching data with python requests & xpath.

```html
<div class="test">
    <p>pppp</p>
    aaa
    <em>bbb</em>
    ccc
    <span>span</span>
</div>
```

I want to get `aaabbbccc`.
I tried `//div/*[not(self::p) and not(self::span)]//text()` to exclude the `p` and `span` element, but it only returns `bbb`.

What is the correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element structure is totally predictable and only the content of text nodes varies, then you can use `//div/node()[not(self::p|self::span)]/descendant-or-self::text()`. Note that this returns a sequence of text nodes, not a single string. This may also return some whitespace text nodes which you may want to filter out with the predicate `[normalize-space(.)]`.

Another possibility would be `//text()[not(parent::p|parent::span)]`.

Comment: Works great as I expected! Thanks.